# Heap error reported by Visual Studio, but only in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a large program that use multiple libraries (SDL, Boost, Chipmunk, Lua, Glew)

When ever I add this code to the a certain Class in the constructor function.

```
std::ifstream is;
is.open ("Sprites/spriteList.json");// Causes Error
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(is,pt);// Causes Error
```

Visual Studio creates a error heap error pointing to this code.

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
        const void * pUserData
        )
{
        if (!pUserData)
            return FALSE;

        if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
            return FALSE;

        return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );
}
```

But only in debug mode, on release it doesn't give a error and runs fine. This error comes up even if I place the code in a block so it will never run.

```
if (false) {
    std::ifstream is;
    is.open ("Sprites/spriteList.json");
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(is,pt);
}
```

Can anyone explain slowly what is going on, or point me to a link to fix it.

Comment: The problem probably occurs in non-debug mode too, but the library doesn't spend any time spotting the problem.  It goes ahead full speed and corrupts the heap, which usually leads to crashes -- although I observe that you claim it doesn't crash (which only shows you've not hit the bug, not that the bug isn't there).

Comment: I'm not sure how it can be corrupting the heap if it's enclosed in a if statement that will never ever run.

Comment: The heap is being corrupted elsewhere.  It's just being spotted here.  That's why memory corruption problems are so insidious.  The problem can be triggered by actions a long way from the point at which they are detected, leading to the infamous [_Heisenbug_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).  Either that, or you are not debugging the same code as you think you are debugging, or you forgot to recompile, or something else along those lines.  On the whole, that's less likely to be the problem than a genuine memory corruption somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a winupdate(20120508) and Visual studio 2010 seems to be really slow debugging afterwards
with a 1 minute delay after compile-to-runDebug lag, then when the debug program exited, another 1 minute delay to 
get control again of visual studio. I did clean all, but no joy.

Solution: I manually deleted the large *.sdf and *.suo files in my project/solution and rebuilt. Issue went away magically.

Not sure why, but something was out of sync, corrupted, or incompatible with the update and needed to be blown away manually.

Comment: I had the same problem and deleting the *.suo file solve my problem, but just temporary. I need to constantly delete that file to get a short temporary solution.